# Need to check if value is between two numbers in a list

Tags: python

I have a list in my python script `[79.99, 82.99, 83.99, 84.99, 85.99, 86.99, 87.99, 88.99, 89.99]` and an ever increasing number in a loop. I want to create a condition so when this number reaches a number between one of those ranges, it will take the lower number of the range and process it.

For example `while (i!=10000): i=+1` and `if i between range(above_range): print(low_Range_number)`

if the number would be 81.99, it would pick 79.99
if the number would be 84.23, it would pick 83.99

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list seems to be sorted, so:

```
def lower_bound(x, l):
    if not l or l[0] > x:
        return
    for i, y in enumerate(l):
        if y > x:
            return l[i - 1]
```

If nothing satisfies your search, it'll return `None`. If not sorted, call `l.sort()` before you do.

Answer (score 8):

This is what the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) stdlib module is made for.

```
import bisect

entries = [79.99, 82.99, 83.99, 84.99, 85.99, 86.99, 87.99, 88.99, 89.99]
x = 81.5

def get_lower_bound(haystack, needle):
    """Get lower bound between two numbers in a sorted list

    If needle is lower than the lower bound, or higher than the higher bound of
    the sorted list, then raise ValueError.

    >>> get_lower_bound([1,2,3], 1.5)
    1
    >>> get_lower_bound([1,2,3], 2)
    2
    >>> get_lower_bound([1,2,3], 0)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ValueError: 0 is out of bounds of [1, 2, 3]
    >>> get_lower_bound([1,2,3], 4)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ValueError: 4 is out of bounds of [1, 2, 3]
    """

    idx = bisect.bisect(haystack, needle)
    if 0 < idx < len(haystack):
        return haystack[idx-1]
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"{needle} is out of bounds of {haystack}")
```

Comment: One small suggestion: You can change `if idx > 0 and idx < len(haystack):` to `if idx > 0 idx < len(haystack):` (Thanks, Pycharm!).

Answer (score 2):

You add your value to the list, sort it, find your value's index and then ask for the previous one (finally remove your value):

```
a = [79.99, 82.99, 83.99, 84.99, 85.99, 86.99, 87.99, 88.99, 89.99]
limit = len(a)
for i in range(0, 10000):
    a.append(i)
    a.sort()
    ix = a.index(i)
    if ix > 0 and ix <= limit: print(a[ix-1])
    a.remove(i)
```